# Neo4j Cypher: how can I "cast" a Node to a Boolean?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've `OPTIONALLY MATCH`'ed a node, and I want to base some value on whether a match was found or not. E.g. this contrived and simplified example:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (node)
RETURN (CASE WHEN node THEN 'yes' ELSE 'false' END) AS result
```

Neo4j unfortunately rejects that with an error message of:

```
Error: Type mismatch: expected Boolean but was Node (line 2, column 19)
"RETURN (CASE WHEN node THEN 'yes' ELSE 'false' END) AS result"
                   ^
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/dnmlu7

How can I achieve this? I've tried `NOT(NOT(node))` but same issue. I've tried `COUNT(node) > 0`, but the error message then says that it's an invalid place for an aggregation. The `?` existence operator doesn't exist in 2.0+ anymore.

I think I'm missing something obvious. Thanks for the help. =)

Comment: Are you looking for something like `OPTIONAL MATCH (node) RETURN node IS NOT NULL`? It would return `true` if there was a match, `false` if not.

Comment: Oh, duh! `node IS NOT NULL` is the answer, thanks. (But no, I need to use this in a `CASE` expression for a different purpose.) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check explicitly (no Crockfordian 'truthiness' here!). To return `true` when a node is matched and `false` when it is not

```
MATCH (node)
RETURN node IS NOT NULL as result
```

and to use in a `CASE` clause

```
MATCH (node)
RETURN CASE WHEN node IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END as result
```